# Sum columns with counts and grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am not too sure how to solve this, but basically I have query that is working fine. What I do is to count individually 6 columns that are results of survey questions. Then on the counts I add them. Now I have to do 3 groups of counts because each result works, Red, Amber and Green, and the user only wants one row. That is to say the total number of reds, amber and greens. However, the user now wants to have result which returns the same information but for each site.

So, is there an easy way where I can get the count for each column or questionnaire category, sum them up so I get a total for red, amber and green, but then group by this for each site? SQL is below, but it works perfectly for one site.

```
   Select production_site, SUM(Green.[Bagging]+Green.[Measurable]+
   Green.[Appearance]+Green.[Aroma]+Green.[Flavour]+Green.[Texture]) as Target,
   SUM(Amber.[Bagging]+Amber.[Measurable]+Amber.[Appearance]+Amber.[Aroma]+
   Amber.[Flavour]+Amber.[Texture]) as Action, SUM(Red.[Bagging]+Red.[Measurable]+
   Red.[Appearance]+Red.[Aroma]+Red.[Flavour]+Red.[Texture]) as Fail
   FROM (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding)
             FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
             WHERE Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding = 'Target'
             AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
             ) As Bagging,
             (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Measurable)
              FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
              WHERE Grocery_Measurable = 'Target'
              AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
              ) As Measurable,
             (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Appearance)
              FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
              WHERE Grocery_Appearance = 'Target'
              AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
              ) As Appearance,
             (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Aroma)
              FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
              WHERE Grocery_Aroma = 'Target'
              AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
              ) As Aroma,
             (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Flavour)
              FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
              WHERE Grocery_Flavour = 'Target'
             AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
             ) As Flavour,
            (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Texture)
             FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
             WHERE Grocery_Texture = 'Target'
            AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
            ) As Texture) AS Green,
    (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding)
             FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
             WHERE Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding = 'Action'
             AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
             ) As Bagging,
            (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Measurable)
             FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
             WHERE Grocery_Measurable = 'Action'
             AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
             ) As Measurable,
            (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Appearance)
             FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
             WHERE Grocery_Appearance = 'Action'
             AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
            ) As Appearance,
           (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Aroma)
            FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
            WHERE Grocery_Aroma = 'Action'
            AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
            ) As Aroma,
           (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Flavour)
            FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
            WHERE Grocery_Flavour = 'Action'
            AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
           ) As Flavour,
           (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Texture)
            FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
            WHERE Grocery_Texture = 'Action'
            AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
           ) As Texture) AS Amber,
    (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Packaging_And_Coding = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Bagging,
          (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Measurable)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Measurable = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Measurable,
          (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Appearance)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Appearance = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Appearance,
          (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Aroma)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Aroma = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Aroma,
          (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Flavour)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Flavour = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Flavour,
          (SELECT COUNT(Grocery_Texture)
           FROM t_Pqe_Grocery
           WHERE Grocery_Texture = 'Fail'
           AND Production_Site = 'Bradford'
          ) As Texture) AS Red,
    t_Pqe_Grocery
    Where Production_Site = 'Bradford'
    Group By production_site
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include your data schema (the column types in your table), some sample data, the output you want from that data, and what you've tried so far yourself that isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [grouping sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx)?

Comment: Can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model and then edit your post showing what you expect the result to be?